# Simple DB scheme gives the "cause cycles or multiple cascade paths" error

Tags: database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have the following 2 tables:

```
    public class Backlink
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Url SourceUrl { get; set; }
        public virtual Url TargetUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class Url
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Backlink> SourceBacklinks { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Backlink> TargetBacklinks { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I have the following fluent API mapping them together:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Backlink>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.SourceUrl)
        .WithMany(x => x.SourceBacklinks);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Backlink>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.TargetUrl)
        .WithMany(x => x.TargetBacklinks);
```

Whenever I try to update the database I get the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.Backlinks_dbo.Urls_SourceUrl_Id' on table 'Backlinks' may
>   cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Could anyone enlighten me regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One-to-many relationships in EF are set to create foreign key constraints that cascade delete by default -- for SQL Server at least? -- and databases usually do not allow a single action to produce multiple cascade paths to the same table.

You have two of those paths going to `Backlink`, so you'll need to set one of those two relationships to not cascade, for example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Backlink>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.TargetUrl)
    .WithMany(x => x.TargetBacklinks)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```